# How to fix this warning : conversion to 'unsigned char' from 'int' may alter its value

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am getting this warning while compiling the library.

warning: conversion to 'unsigned char' from 'int' may alter its value

This prevents us from using compiler option -Werror.

Can anyone suggest the way to fix this warning ???

Comment: What's the actual code triggering that warning?

Comment: You need to post the code around RTMessage.inl:166

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shoot in the dark:

Use a `static_cast` to instruct the compiler that you know that the conversion will not result into a truncation: `int i; unsigned char c = static_cast<unsigned char>(i);`

If you are not so sure, check out `boost::numeric_cast`.

It's equivalent to `static_cast` in this case, but much more explicit (easier to grep / search for numeric conversions). Also, it performs bound checkings.

Comment: .Thanks for your reply. We are getting warning in this type of scenario in our library _flags&= ~x where x is int and _flags is unsigned char. How should we use static_cast here to remove the warning?

Comment: @Kundan: `_flags &= static_cast<unsigned char>(~x);`, but are you sure that `~x` does indeed do what you want ? It would be simpler if `x` was of `unsigned char` type before you actually attempted bit operations on it.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler is warning you that an `int` can contain values that doesn't fit in an `unsigned char`.

If you are **absolutely sure** that in this case it will always fit, you can tell that to the compiler by using a `static_cast`

```
c = static_cast<unsigned char>(i);
```

The the compiler will trust you on that (and it is your fault if it isn't true).

Comment: May not be a fault at all if it doesn't fit. As long as what you want is the value of `i` modulo `UCHAR_MAX+1`, in an `unsigned char`, then that's what this gives you. The cast tells the compiler that you want that result, not that `i` will always be in the range `0-UCHAR_MAX` :-) If you do expect the value to be in range, then `boost::numeric_cast` expresses that more precisely, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious answer is to find out how to disable that warning on your compiler.  From other comments, you're doing:

```
flags &= ~x;
```

A compiler which warns on this typical idiom is brain dead.